# Car radio which equalizes voice volume on talk radio

Tags: audio, sound-system

I listen to a lot of talk radio when I drive. It is very frustrating when one talker seems to whisper and one to almost shout The radio stations seem to do nothing about this. In fact my favourite show has a presenter who seems to whisper, so that when talk switches from him to someone else, I have to keep jiggling the volume control, which is both annoying and potentially dangerous.

Any suggestions?

---

[Update] Hoping to avoid any more downvotes. I came here to ask what hardware to buy, not how to install it.

If someone can recommend a car radio that does what I ask, then I can contact the manufacturer & ask if it is compatible.

There surely can't be that much difference between them, can there? If it is so important, then it should fit a 1991 Mazda MX5 Miata

Comment: What does it need to be compatible with?

Comment: A car? :-) Seriously, I don't know enough about h/w to say. Is it enough if I say that it has to be compatible with a 1991 US model Mazda MX5 Miata?

Comment: It would be more useful if you could tell us (or show us, that would also work) the type of connector you're going to need to connect it to.

Comment: Alas, I am totally clueless when it coem to h/w (I am a programmer, so that's to be expected ;-) I woudl not even know wht to google for. I can only say 1991 US model Mazda MX5 Miata. But even if you can confirm that such things exist, that's a steo forward. If you can point me at one, or tell me what to gooogle for, then I can contact the manufacturer

Comment: Presumably you know where in your car you're going to install it? What cables are there? Could you show us those cables?

Comment: All that I know is that I will repace the existing radio. I wouldn't know how to remove it to take a pc of the existing cables. Do you know of a car radio with voice level equalization? If so, I can conatc the manufacturer

Comment: I would suggest that if you don't even know how to remove the old radio yet, you're not ready to be asking about new radios. Figure out what you need to do.

Comment: I think we are talking a cross purposes here. It will not be me who swaps out the radio. The garage can do that at the next service I am just looking for a recommendation of what to purchase.

Comment: In that case, your garage will be able to advise you about what you need to look for in a radio for it to be compatible with your car. You should ask them, and post that in this question.